# Flask Gunicorn not applying my new code changes

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

I am developing a flask webapp, and during development I test my app with `run.py`.

run.py:

```
from my_app import app
from my_app.config import (WEBSERVER_PORT)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=WEBSERVER_PORT, debug=True)
```

However, I am planning to serve my app with gunicorn in production and I am seeing descrepencies when I run the app with gunicorn. For example, I added a new button to my webapp, and I can only see the new button with I use `run.py` to run the app. But when I use gunicorn to serve my app like this:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi
```

The app runs with no errors, however, I don't see the new button. Here is my wsgi.py:

```
from my_app import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

And here is how I serve it:

```
(venv)# gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi
[2018-11-19 10:35:52 -0800] [16644] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-11-19 10:35:52 -0800] [16644] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (16644)
[2018-11-19 10:35:52 -0800] [16644] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-11-19 10:35:52 -0800] [16647] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16647
```

So my question is, does Gunicorn cache any of your changes, because I only see my old code when serving with gunicorn. Or is there anything I have to do to get the new changes in before running it with Gunicorn?

Comment: My issue is different than the ones you posted above. I'm not trying to autoreload, I am actually completely stopping the gunicorn workers and restarting it, but i still see the same old code. This has nothing to do with autoreload.

Comment: did you find the source of your problem?

Comment: I am having the same issue and still have not found any solution. By any chance have you found the workaround ?

Comment: @lion_bash find any workarounds?